# How can I install the pyldap package on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, python-3.5, pyldap

I've been trying to add the pyldap package using pip from the command line :

```
pip install pyldap
```

But i'm getting this error :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.25.1 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -Ic:\python\include -Ic:\python\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
>       LDAPObject.c
>
> c:\users\myUser\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-tzxw0vq9\pyldap\modules\errors.h(8): fatal error C1083: **Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory**
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I've installed OpenLDAP for Windows, but it didn't change a thing.

Can pyldap be install on windows 10?  Am i missing a prerequisite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to install the pyldap package using the wheel file from this website :

[Gohlke's wheels](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyldap)